# Android Sharing Intent only works with Google Photos, Crashes Other Apps

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to create a Sharing Intent for an Android App to share images to other apps. However, I'm getting this really weird result when implementing this feature.

I have a share button that when I click on the button, it runs the following method:

```
private void shareIntent() {
    Uri currUri = Uri.parse(data.get(pos).getUrl());
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, currUri);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/jpg");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.share_to)));
}
```

data.get(pos).getUrl() returns the URL of a custom class I made that implements Parcelable, and when printing it out, it returns a directory like the following: "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/primitive/Primitive-79538313.jpg"

The intent works at first, opening the sharing menu. However, when I click on most applications, it either crashes the application or it gives an error... except with Google Photos, which uploads the photo properly to the gallery.

Firstly, I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong to cause this issue in the other apps. Also, I'd like to know if someone has an explanation as to why only Google Photos allows the sharing feature to work, while many of the other apps I've tested do not.

For reference, here are some examples I've run with the sharing intent. When I try to share the image, it crashes Hangouts. It gives a "failed to load image" error message in Snapchat, "Unable to share file" in Slack and Gmail, "Upload was unsuccessful" in Drive, "Messenger was unable to process the file" in, well, Messenger, and "Couldn't load image" in GroupMe. It doesn't load the image in Facebook but doesn't crash nor give an error.

Thank you for any help or feedback you can provide!

**EDIT:**
This seemed to work without trying to get around App Permissions:

```
 private void shareIntent() {
    File imageFile = new File(data.get(pos).getUrl());
    Uri uriToImage = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", imageFile);
    Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(DetailActivity.this)
            .setStream(uriToImage)
            .getIntent();
    shareIntent.setData(uriToImage);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image"));
}
```

Thank you to everyone that responded!

Comment: Put image/jpeg instant of jpg

Comment: I tried that and, unfortunately, that doesn't resolve the issue...

Comment: Check the below answer. if it doesn't work. share your error log here

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I got an error that I believe is attributed to Android N changing it's FileProvider implementation.
Here's the error I got:
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/primitive/Primitive-9088538005279302268.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
                                                                                 at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1958)
                                                                                 at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2348)

Comment: Check weather your image is in the same folder with same name

Comment: Check my edited code below

Comment: Awesome, it works now. Thank you so much!

Comment: no problem. Hope that worked. Happy coding.

Comment: For me, the missing key element was `intent.setDataAndType(uri, contentResolver.getType(uri))`